# Rails 5.1.5 upgrade causes - uninitialized constant Mime::JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

Whenever a controller renders json I get, 
`uninitialized constant Mime::JSON`
I have not modified any code related to this.

Ex, the code for this controller method that throws the error:

`def names
    @families = Family.pluck(:name)
    render json: @families
  end`

This was working fine before the rails 5 upgrade.

Comment: I think the issue is using the responders gem.  I had to use the normal respond_to do |format|, syntx in order for it to render correctly.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was jbuilder causing this error.

Upgrading jbuilder to latest (2.7.0 at time of writing) solved this. The old jbuilder references JSON wrong and causes responder to fail.

Answer (score 2):

I was obtaining the error after upgrade from rails 5.0.1 to 5.1.0 and in my case the `gem 'web-console','~> 2.0'` was causing the error, I solved it updating it to `gem 'web-console','>= 3.3.0'`.